# Converting symbol to string

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

```
var TitleVal = encodeURIComponent($("[title='Title Required Field']").val()); // Title has value "car & bus"
//decodeURIComponent(TitleVal); 

var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title='Name'] option"); //Name is other column,

[].some.call(allOptions, function(option) {
        if (option.innerHTML == TitleVal) {
            option.selected = "selected";
            return true;
        }
    });
```

how would I make the symbol in string as normal string?

Comment: I believe looking for decoding the string.

Comment: small snippet, what i have understood from your query: 
var t = 'A & B'
var t1 = encodeURIComponent(t)
"A%20%26%20B"
decodeURIComponent(t1)
'A & B'

Comment: in if conditiont the value should come without %20%26 but then it again considers & as symbol n the condition is false

Comment: In If condition can't you use decodeURIComponent(option.innerHTML)  and check. Hope i have understood your problem

Comment: Does it helped you

Comment: i did that, but it is not converting the symbol same, amp is still there.

Comment: what is your value in Title Required Field

Comment: `India & China`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34294/discussion-between-ravindra-and-vikash-kumar).

Comment: Instead of & it added %26amp%3B when i used encodeURIComponent(option.innerHTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor change and it worked..

```
TitleVal =encodeURIComponent($("[title='Title Required Field']").val());

var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title='Name'] option");

[].some.call(allOptions, function(option) {
    if (encodeURIComponent(option.text) == TitleVal) {
        option.selected = "selected";
        return true;
    }
});
```